# Save each slide of powerpoint as image(png) using python

Tags: python-pptx

I want to save each slide of PowerPoint presentation as image and also save each slide as separate PowerPoint file using python. Can anyone help me with that

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately python-pptx can't do any of that. You're going to have use either VBA or AppleScript, depending on your platform.